# Fields Parameter in Google Drive API V3

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I'm trying to retrieve user info via Google Drive API v3.

```
var request = this.driveService.About.Get();
request.Fields = "user.displayName";

var accountInfo = await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

Even though I specify the fields it complains with the message:

Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
The 'fields' parameter is required for this method. [400]

Does it mean something else by 'fields'?

Answer (score 2):

I had to use Oauth2Service instead of DriveService, like this:

```
var request = this.authService.Userinfo.Get();

request.Fields = "email";

var accountInfo = await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it still works, but this worked for me in the past:

```
        'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/about?fields=user',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(googleDriveAccessToken);
    credential.refreshToken();

apachetransport = GoogleApacheHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(); 

Drive service = new  Drive.Builder(apachetransport, JSON_FACTORY,credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

Get get = service.about().get();

com.google.api.services.drive.model.About about = get.setFields("user").execute();

User user = about.getUser();

System.out.println(user.getEmailAddress());
```